# SQL Server Conversion Fails on different server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that has an `Isnumeric` conversion that fails on one server and runs fine on another.

Both servers are using SQL Server 2012. The database is a copy on the second server.

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '700.00' to data type int

The main select actually returns no rows.

```
voidOrDenied = (case when isnumeric(c.reasonpending) = 1 and 
                      cast(left(c.reasonpending, charindex(',', c.reasonpending+',')-1) as int)
                        between 1 and 25 then 'Void'
                      when c.reasonpending like '%void%' then 'Void'
                      else 'Denied' end),
```

What could be different on the second server?

Comment: It seems to be a decimal separator issue : you cut your string on the comma ```,``` location and you receive 700.00 so the decimal separator is a dot ```.```. ```cast(left(c.reasonpending, charindex(',', REPLACE(c.reasonpending, '.',',') +',')-1)``` should prevent this from happening

Comment: This looks like a case of different database collations. Many Latin based languages the '.' and ',' are oposite to the English and the like languages

Answer (score 0):

Use `try_cast()`:

```
(case when try_cast(left(c.reasonpending, charindex(',', c.reasonpending+',')-1) as int) between 1 and 25
      then 'Void'
      when c.reasonpending like '%void%' then 'Void'
      else 'Denied'
end)
```

Comment: Yes try_cast will work.  I'm still curious as to why one server  throws the error with isnumeric and the other does not.  Same collation on the servers.  The error occurs on the server where the db's are restored from production.  No error on the production server.

Comment: @MAnthony . . . Because SQL -- in general -- does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, so there is no guarantee that the `isnumeric()` is calculated before the `cast()`.